# How to correctly create a symbolic link to the Python interpreter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, symlink, python-venv, site-packages

On Ubuntu 18.04, I installed Python 3.7 and a virtual environment in `/home/sss/dev/venv/3.7` The venv site packages are in `/home/sss/dev/venv/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages` -

```
~/dev/venv/3.7/bin/python -m site
sys.path = [
    '/home/sss/dev',
    '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
    '/home/sss/dev/venv/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/shane/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/shane/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: False
```

Next, I created a symbolic link in my home directory targeting the Python interpreter in the virtual environment -

```
ln -s /home/sss/dev/venv/3.7/bin/python ~/py
ls -l  py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 sss sss 35 feb  5 08:52 py -> /home/sss/dev/venv/3.7/bin/python
```

but when I use this link in place of `/home/sss/dev/venv/3.7/bin/python`, I would expect it to have access to packages in `/home/sss/dev/venv/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages`, but this is not the case -

```
./py -m site
sys.path = [
    '/home/sss/dev',
    '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7',
    '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
    '/home/sss/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/sss/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/sss/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

Is there a work-around to this problem?

Comment: Can't reproduce this issue. Seems to work as expected for me.

Comment: @sinoroc I have just double-checked and I get the same results as stated above. However, if I first activate the virtual environment with `source ~/dev/venv/3.7/bin/activate` then I see the virtual environment's `site-packages` directory in `sys.path`. Was your virtual environment activated when you tried to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Oh, I think I got what the issue is. It wasn't clear to me where the `py` link was placed, so I assumed it was in the `venv/3.7/bin` directory, but it isn't, is it? Where is the `py` link?

Comment: @sinoroc No, the link to /home/sss/dev/venv/3.7/bin/python was placed in a separate directory. I will update my question to make that clear.

Comment: I am pretty sure this can't work then. `py` would need to find some files in directories relative to its location, example it looks for `../pyvenv.cfg`. If it can't find it, then it's not a virtual environment. See my answer for a possible alternative with a shell script, that could potentially still offer the intended behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this can't work. The location of `py` matters. In order to take into account the *virtual environment*, `py` would look for some specific files at locations relative to its own. For example it would look for `../pyvenv.cfg` and if it can't find that file then the virtual environment is completely ignored (whether it is active or not doesn't matter in such a case). I believe `py` has to be in the virtual environment's `bin` directory and nowhere else.

---

Not sure exactly what the original intention is, but maybe you could write a `py` *shell wrapper* instead of a symbolic link, such as the following (just an example, it probably needs to be improved to be really useful):

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

/home/sss/dev/venv/3.7/bin/python "$@"
```

Such a script could be placed anywhere and it would always take the virtual environment into account.